# How to approach $\phi: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ such that $\vec F = \nabla\phi.$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm looking through exam papers and I'm lost on what to do when asked to find a function
$\phi: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R  $  such that $ \vec F = \nabla\phi.$

An example of a question I'm looking at is as follows:

Let
    $$\ F(x,y,z)=(2xy+4xz)i +(x^2+6yz)j +(2x^2+3y^2)k, \quad x,y,z\in \Bbb R. $$

(a) Find a function $\phi : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ such that $ \vec F = \nabla\phi.$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This should help you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788153/compute-the-following-line-integral-along-a-path-of-your-choice-finding-potenti/1788160#1788160

Comment: from $\phi(x_0)$ and $\nabla \phi$, you can deduce the value of $\phi(x)$ for every $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the definition: $\nabla \phi = (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z})$

Hence, you have to solve:

$$\begin{cases} 2xy + 4xz =\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}  \\ x^2 + 6yz = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} \\ 2x^2 + 3y^2 = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} \end{cases}$$

The first equation gives: $\phi(x,y,z) = \int (2xy + 4xz )dx = x^2 y + 2x^2z + f(y,z)$ for some function $f$. Substituting in the second equation: $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2 y + 2x^2z + f(x,y)) = x^2 + 6yz$, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 6yz$, hence $f(y,z) = 3y^2z + g(z)$ for some function $g$.

Substitute in the third equation to find $g$ and finally get $\phi$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Bbb R^3$ is simply connected, such $\phi$ will exist if and only if $\nabla \times F = 0 $, so it is always good to check if this is the case, so you don't waste time. You want to solve $$ \begin{cases} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,y,z) = 2xy + 4xz \\ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}(x,y,z) = x^2 + 6yz \\ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}(x,y,z) = 2x^2 + 3y^2    \end{cases} $$ Take the first equation and integrate w.r.t. $x$ to obtain $\phi(x,y,z) = x^2y + 2x^2z + g(y,z)$. Now differentiate that in $y$ and plug in the second equation to find $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$. Then integrate in $y$ to get $g(y,z) = {\rm something} + h(z)$. Now put that back in the expression for $\phi$. Differentiate in $z$ and compare with the third equation in display to find $h'(z)$, and hence $\phi$. This is the standard procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The task poses a system of partial derivatives:
$$
\partial_x \phi = 2xy + 4xz \\
\partial_y \phi = x^2 + 6yz \\
\partial_z \phi = 2x^2 + 3y^2
$$
Integration gives
$$
\phi = x^2y + 2x^2z + f(y,z) \\
\phi = x^2y + g(x,z) +  3y^2z \\
\phi = h(x,y) + 2x^2z + 3y^2z
$$
Comparison gives
$$
\phi = x^2 y + 2 x^2 z + 3 y^2 z + C
$$
where $C$ is some constant.